# C# to VB.NET Event Conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net, event-handling

Porting an application from C# (1.1 framework) to VB.NET (3.5 framework), and I have this one last event based issue I cannot get my head around.

This is the original C# code

```
public delegate void SpecialEventHandler(object sender,SpecialEventArgs e);
public event SpecialEventHandler SpecialEvent = null;

_SpecialLogWriter  SpecialWriter = new _SpecialLogWriter(this.SpecialEvent);
```

This is the converted VB.NET code

```
Public Delegate Sub SpecialEventHandler(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as SpecialEventArgs)
Public Event SpecialEvent as SpecialEventHandler

Dim SpecialWriter as New _SpecialLogWriter(Me.SpecialEvent)
```

The SpecialLogWriter constructor is expecting a SpecialEventHandler, but the Me.SpecialEvent in the constructor of SpecialLogWriter gives me the error message that this is an event and cannot be called directly.

Am I missing another delegate, or is this just one of this declaration issues between the languages?

Comment: I can't seem to create an event with a return type.  Any help on my post would be appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624886/vb-equivalent-of-c-event-creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am forced to wonder if the original code worked properly to begin with. I simply removed the event tag from the SpecialEvent declaration, and all seems to be working at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You say the constructor expects event handler but you're passing an event, not event handler. Shouldn't you use:

```
Dim SpecialWriter as New _SpecialLogWriter(New SpecialEventArgs())
```